# Stuck on splash screen, does not progress to login manager

Tags: xorg, lightdm, upstart, gdm, display-manager

My login manager stopped loading, for no apparent reason, instead tty7 was a black screen I could type into but with no effect. I tried several variations of `service lightdm restart` `service sddm restart` but to no avail. I tried installing `gdm` and running `dpkg-reconfigure` but this showed some strange error `intel ... ERROR too many voltage tries give up`. I also tried installing `xdm` but it also didn't work. I tried enabling the display managers with `systemctl enable gdm.service` `systemctl enable lightdm.service`. It seems x11 is okay as `sudo startx` starts unity seemingly okay.

Finally I gave up and restarted. Now I just get the kubuntu splash screen which never resolves to a display manager or to a `tty`.

Maybe I have enabled several display managers? What should I try and do next? I am currently using a try ubuntu live usb, how could I modify upstart or systemd to just enable `lightdm` for example?

Hope I don't have to format :-/ come on internet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay turns out the `[drm:intel_dp_start_link_train] *ERROR* too many voltage retries, give up` from the kernel is a [known bug](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180731) but was a red herring and had nothing to do with my problems and from what I've seen people say it's not a problem. I think it has something to do with ASUS. I am using ASUS TaiChi 21.

Also running `systemctl enable` for several login managers wasn't too much of a problem as it just creates symbolic links in `/etc/systemd/system`

I fixed the splash screen not progressing to the login manager by changing the login manager to `sddm`, it was set to `xdm`. I did this by using a "Try ubuntu live" usb stick and modifying the file `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` from `/usr/bin/xdm` to `/usr/bin/sddm`.

In the process I learnt a little about how X11 and display managers work:

- X11 is a network protocol. It encodes things such as graphic primitives, images, pointer motion, and key presses.
- Xorg is an X server. It implements X11 and provides an interface to keyboards, mice, and video cards.
- gdm, xdm, kdm sddm are all login managers (synonym display managers) They are the first X program run by the system.
- When the computer boots, the shell scripts in `/etc/rc2.d` are run. There is a script for each login manager such as `S03lightdm`. This login manager script reads from `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` and decides whether to init the display manager based on this value.
- Upon authentication the login manager calls `/etc/Xsession` which calls the scripts in `/etc/Xsession.d/` and `~/xinitrc` which then sets up your desktop environment and window manager.

So presumably there was something wrong with either the installation/config/compatibility of xdm on my computer.

Following this change I was able to see the login manager screen and was able to login but upon login it redirected me back to the login screen. This occurred due to running `sudo startx` which [created the file](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1036830) `~/.Xauthority` but owned by root. I finally fixed this by deleting `.Xauthority` and everything is back to normal!